# Create fakefile warning

Tags: extension

I have seen this warning on a couple of sites.

Warning: file_put_contents(.../sites/default/civicrm/ext/delete-this-DEbcrmuyt7): failed to open stream: Permission denied in CRM_Utils_File::createFakeFile() (line 306 of /.../sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php).

On one site this warning then came up when we tried to delete a Price Set but were unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

We have provided a fix for this at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10677